# How do I specify multiple types for a parameter using type-hints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a Python function which accepts XML data as an `str`.

For convenience, the function also checks for `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` and will automatically convert to `str` if necessary.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def post_xml(data: str):
    if type(data) is ET.Element:
        data = ET.tostring(data).decode()
    # ...
```

Is it possible to specify with type-hints that a parameter can be given as one of two types?

```
def post_xml(data: str or ET.Element):
    # ...
```

Comment: Is this really a duplicate? I mean, the syntax is the same, but the semantics aren't, are they? I seem to remember something like, "functions should be contravariant on their inputs and covariant on their outputs", which means a function that can accept multiple types makes much more sense than a function that can *return* multiple types.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You want a type [union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-union). For Python 3.10+:

```
def post_xml(data: str | ET.Element):
```

For earlier versions:

```
from typing import Union

def post_xml(data: Union[str, ET.Element]):
    ...
```

Comment: Pycharm's parameter info interprets `Union[str, ET.Element]` as [`Union[str, Element, Element]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Trmd.png).

Comment: So this is not even supported in python <= 9

Comment: @Drizzle Come again?