# Accepting generic Enum values of certain types

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I would like to write a function accepting any value of any `enum.Enum`, as long as its value is either a `str` or an `int`. It shall work with enums mixing int and str values.

E.g, if I have:

```
class E(Enum):
    a = 0
    b = "abc"
```

- I do want to allow passing a value like `E.a` and `E.b`, without actually "knowing" `E` (any Enum might be used).
- I do not want to rely on passing `E.a.value` or using dictionaries instead. Therefore, just checking the parameter for int or str is not sufficiant.

Is it possible to define this as a type hint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify multiple types for a parameter using type-hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709104/how-do-i-specify-multiple-types-for-a-parameter-using-type-hints)

Comment: No. I know how to ensure if a parameter is either str or int. However, I want to ensure a parameter is any Enum-element with a value of type int or str. So given any parameter p, I want to ensure (1) its value-attribute is either int or str, and (2) the following is true: isinstance(type(p), enum.EnumMeta). However, I could live with a single-solution for (2), and check for int/str value within the function.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question then. I am not sure if this is possible just as a type hint.

Comment: ... that exactly is my question ;)

Comment: I see. I think I missunderstood your reply then.

Comment: mixed values within the enumeration will be a common case. I edited my question, I hope it's more explicit now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be possible, just not in the way you describe exactly. I wouldn't say forcing the argument to be an enumeration is the way to go here. Rather, I would make the enumerations *behave* like the types you want. There's already an [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum) like that in the standard library.

You want your function to accept strings or integers. That's easy.

```
def foo(arg: Union[str, int]):
    pass
```

Now all that's left is defining enumerations that are strings and integers. If you don't want to use the standard `IntEnum`, you can easily define it yourself.

```py
class IntEnum(int, enum.Enum):
    a = 1
    b = 4

class StrEnum(str, enum.Enum):
    a = 'a'
    b = 'b'

print(IntEnum.a + IntEnum.b) # -> 5
print(StrEnum.a + StrEnum.b) # -> 'ab'
```

Or you can use them as parent classes if you don't define any real members. However, if you want to have strings and integers in one enumeration, then you probably are better off just calling `enum.value`. If you like tricks, that could be done for exampe in a decorator, but this is a bit overkill. Wouldn't recommend it necessarily.

```py
from functools import wraps

def enum_value(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(arg):
        if isinstance(arg, enum.Enum):
            arg = arg.value
        return func(arg)
    return wrapper

@enum_value
def foo(arg: Union[str, int]):
    print(arg, type(arg))

foo(StrEnum.a) # -> a <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Indeed, strings and ints might be mixed within the enumeration. Beside the overhead, a downside to the workaround would be that type hinting support within Pycharm would possibly break and complain about wrong typed function calls.

Comment: Thought this over again. A solution I can live with, is using the StrEnum and use only Strings (e.g. '1'). If the type-conversion to int fails, I will treat it as str. I do not have to differentiate between 1 and "1", so therefore I'm fine with that. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you found this helpful. It's not that your original problem cannot be solved necessarily, but it rang in my head as weird somehow. And in my experience that's usually a sign of me making a poor design choice. Best of luck!

Comment: Yes. Probably mixing types whithin an enumeration is not what those are intended for in the first place ;D